# Assembly , syscall not work as expected. Ubuntu Linux x86_64 , using AT&T syntax

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc, system-calls

I am testing use of .bss for allocation of a memory area to hold a single number. Then print that number to console. The output is not as expected. I am supposed to get e number (12), but get a newline.

System config:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 5.8.0-48-generic #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 13:40:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

description: CPU
product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8350U CPU @ 1.70GHz
```

The code:

```
# compile with: gcc -ggdb -nostdlib -no-pie  test.s -o test

.bss
.lcomm          output,1

.global _start
.text

_start:
        # test .bss and move numer 12 to rbx where memory are allocated in .bss
        mov     $output, %rbx    # rbx to hold address of allocated space
        mov     $12,%rdx          # Move a number to rdx
        mov     %rdx,(%rbx)       # Move content in rdx to the address where rbx points to (e.g ->output)

        # setup for write syscall:  
        mov     $1,%rax          # system call for write, according to syscall table (http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/)
        mov     $1,%rdi          # fd = 1, stdout
        mov     $output,%rsi     # adress of string to output moved to rsi
        mov     $1,%rdx          # number of bytes to be written

        syscall                  # should write 12 in console

        mov     $60,%rax
        xor     %rdi,%rdi
        syscall                 # exit normally
```

I have set a breakpoint with the first syscall (using GDB), to look into the registers:

```
i r rax rbx rdx rdi rsi

rax            0x1                 1
rbx            0x402000            4202496
rdx            0x1                 1
rdi            0x1                 1
rsi            0x402000            4202496

x/1 0x402000
0x402000 <output>:  12
```

The output after syscall is blank, was expected to get the number "12":

```
:~/Dokumenter/ASM/dec$ gcc -ggdb -nostdlib -no-pie  test.s -o test
:~/Dokumenter/ASM/dec$ ./test

:~/Dokumenter/ASM/dec$ ./test

:~/Dokumenter/ASM/dec$
```

So, my question is, are there any obvious explanation of why I am getting blank and not 12 ?

Comment: It wrote the byte 12, which in ASCII is a form feed.  If you want to see the two characters `12`, you need to write those two characters, e.g. `1` is ASCII code 49 (`0x31`).  The `write` system call won't do binary-to-decimal conversion for you.

Comment: By the way, your `mov %rdx,(%rbx)` writes 8 bytes into a variable that only has space for 1.  You are going to want to learn about operand size.  However, that sequence of three instructions can be replaced by `movb $12, output`.

Comment: Thanks, but even if i increase the size to 8, (`.lcomm          output,8`), and write different bytelength (2,4,8) - (`mov     $8,%rdx`), it still just prints a newline.. Also simplified the code to test movb, but same result..         (`movb     $12,output`)
`mov     $2,%rdx          # number of bytes to be written`

Comment: Yeah, because you are now writing out the two bytes `12, 0` which will NOT display as the numerals `1` and `2`; it's a form feed followed by a null character.  You have to write out the two bytes `49, 50`.  To see what I mean, do `movb $49, output` and `movb $50, output+1`.  Look at `man ascii` to see what numerical values correspond to what characters.

Comment: You can also write `movb $'1', output` and the assembler will work out the correct ASCII value for you.

Comment: Thanks again @Nate. I finally got it; Doing this with UTF-8. Had to use two bytes for each number: `  movb     $0x31,output    
                 movb     $0x32,output+1    and  mov     $2,%rdx`     So,, next thing is to try and create an UTF-8 converter :-) Thanks again.

Comment: I think you may still be confused.  The `$0x31` is **one** byte.  It corresponds to the **character** `1`.  The **number** twelve needs **two** characters to display it, because it has two decimal digits, even though its numerical value can be stored in a single byte.  UTF-8 incorporates ASCII so there is no difference between them in this case.

Comment: There's an example of a binary-to-decimal conversion routine at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835456/printing-an-integer-as-a-string-with-att-syntax-with-linux-system-calls-instea/45851398#45851398.

Comment: Hi again Nate I got the two byte part. My answer back were probably not clear about that. Thanks for the link, I’ll try implement that, so I can have different numbers displayed. Not only ‘12’ :-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov     $output,%rsi     # address of string to output moved to rsi
                                      ^^^^^^
```

Address of ***string.*** The value `$12` is *not* the character sequence `"12"`. If you wanted to print the string `12`, you would need to load `0x31` and `0x32` (`'1'` and `'2'`) into the memory area (making it big enough) the use `2` as the length.

For example, `movw $0x3231, output` or better `movw $0x3231, output(%rip)` to use RIP-relative addressing for static data, like normal for x86-64.  (Unlike NASM, GAS syntax doesn't `$'12'` as a way to write the same integer constant.)

If you want to print an integer as a string, you'll probably want to manipulate it mathematically so you can do it one digit at a time.  ([Printing an integer as a string with AT&T syntax, with Linux system calls instead of printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45835456/printing-an-integer-as-a-string-with-att-syntax-with-linux-system-calls-instea))

Comment: Thanks. I got it!! Had to use two bytes for each number: ` movb $0x31,output movb $0x32,output+1 and mov $2,%rdx`

Comment: @MartinHaneferd: You can of course do store both byte values as part of one word store; see my edit.  (Remember x86 is little-endian).  Also, since you're putting the address into a register anyway, might as well use RSI which you eventually want for the syscall, instead of separately using RBX.  `mov $2, %edx` is a more efficient way to write a small positive integer into a 64-bit register.  Not everything should be 64-bit operand-size, for example `mov %rdx,(%rbx)` is a 64-bit store.

Comment: @Martin, there's nothing in your comment addressing my "making it big enough" comment (though you may have done so without commenting). If not, you probably want to ensure the `.lcomm` allocates more than a single byte.

Comment: @paxdiablo , Yes, I increased the .lcomm with two bytes. I also figured out that by slicing the number into two digits (bytes) and then add 0x30 to each of them and put in byte 1 and 2, it worked. So the main answer to my problem where that presenting a regular number to text/string, it has to be converted to ascii first. So, once again., thanks for answer. My head is back on track :-)