# Referencing stack pointer into register for syscall - GNU GAS AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to put a reference to my stack pointer into the `%rsi` register so that the syscall will get the struct from i's second parameter.

here is the code :

```
01: mov $0x2a, %al
02 : mov $3, %rdi
03 : push $0x02
04 : push $0x0068
05 : push $0x5c11
06 : push $0xa8c0
07 : push $0x1401
08 : mov (%rsp), %r13
09 : mov %r13, %rsi # this is where I get lost
10 : mov $0x10, %dl
11 : syscall
```

strace ./helloWorld give me this :

```
connect(3, 0x5c11, 16)
exit(0)
```

My question is : how can I pass a struct that I have put on the stack to the rsi register (by passing the pointer of the stack)

What I have tryied so far :

- Reading about GNU syntax
- passing the reference directly without intermediate register

  ```
  08 : #mov (%rsp), %r13
  09 : mov %rsi, (%rsp)
  ```
- using pointer deplacement

  ```
  03 : mov $0x02 (%rsp)
  04 : movw $0x0068 2(%rsp)
  05 : movw $0x5c11 4(%rsp)
  06 : movw $0xa8c0 6(%rsp)
  07 : movw $0x1401 8(%rsp)
  08 : # mov (%rsp), %r13
  09 : mov (%rsp), %rsi

  strace ./hellowWorld:
  ...
  connect(3, 0xa8c05c1100680002, 16)
  ...
  ```

Every time I have in the second argument is the value of the registers or the stacks, not a pointer.

Using NASM syntax, Everything is ok.

I am using theses resources :

- http://6.s081.scripts.mit.edu/sp18/x86-64-architecture-guide.html
- https://syscalls.w3challs.com/?arch=x86_64
- Youtube : x86-64 GNU Assembler Crash-Course From "Write your own Operating System"
- Youtube : How to Write Shellcode playlist From "Tactical Network Solutions"

Comment: You do not want the indirection. Just do `mov %rsp, %rsi`.

Comment: (FYI, it's [register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register), not a [registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registry).)

Comment: @Jester, ok, that worked Oo. I don't understand though. Ains't you supposed to pass a pointer ? Does the %rsp register alway leads to the stack pointer ?

Comment: The rsp *is* the stack pointer; it points to the top byte on the stack.  The rsp register holds the value that is the address of the top of stack, aka the stack *pointer*.  If you dereference the stack pointer you'll get items/bytes/words that are on the stack.

Comment: @ErikEidt, Ah Is see. This was my mistake. I though this register was like any other, and if I want to pass a pointer and not a value, I have to do something more. But stack register gives the start of the stack pointer. Nothing to do more.
Thanks a lot, this was really usefull !

Comment: Ok, good.  FYI, all the registers are like that though, holding simple values that sometimes happen to be addresses.

Comment: FYI, your two version aren't equivalent.  Your version with `push` is using `pushq $sign_extended_imm32`, so you're pushing $0x0000000000005c11` into 8 bytes by itself.  If you want to push 8 bytes of data where the top 4 is non-zero, `mov $0x12345678abcdef, %rcx` / `push %rcx` or something.  (Pick any tmp register).  Or `push` and `mov $imm32, 4(%rsp)` but that takes more bytes around the immediates.

Comment: [Printing an integer as a string with AT&T syntax, with Linux system calls instead of printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45835456) is a near duplicate, includes a working example as part of making a `write` system call, although the data gets onto the stack via `mov` stores, not `push`.