# x86-64 GNU print value of register to terminal -- ubuntu

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, system-calls, gnu

As the question title suggests, I'm trying to print the value of a register inside a for-loop I wrote. I am quite experienced with assembly, but not with printing stuff (or even writing assembly for that matter -- all of my experience has been with debugging and reading assembly in class). Here's what I have so far:

```
.global  _start
.data
msg:
    .ascii "msg\n"
    len = . - msg
.text
_start:
        mov    $0x0, %r12d
    test:
    cmp $0x5, %r12d
    jg end
    loop:
        mov    $0x4,%eax
        mov    $0x1,%ebx
        mov    $msg,%ecx
        mov    $len,%edx
        int    $0x80
    add    $0x1, %r12d
    jmp test
    end:
        mov    $0x1,%al
    mov    $0x0,%ebx
    int    $0x80
```

instead of printing "msg" inside the for-loop, I want to print the value of %r12d, but when I try to use `mov    %r12d,%ecx` instead of `mov    $msg,%ecx`, I don't end up with anything printed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `%r12d` isn't a pointer to ASCII chars in memory, which is what the `write` system call wants.  `strace ./a.out` will show you `write` returned `-EFAULT`. See [Printing an integer as a string with AT&T syntax, with Linux system calls instead of printf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45851398)